# Ionic - EACCES (Permission denied) error when uploading video

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I'm having some difficulties trying upload video file to server using [Cordova Camera Plugin](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-camera/) and [cordova-plugin-advanced-http](https://github.com/silkimen/cordova-plugin-advanced-http). The code works like a charm when uploading an **image** from gallery, but no matter what I do, I always receive `EACCES (Permission denied)` when uploading a **video** from gallery:

```
file url ->  file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/VID_20200908_114957.mp4
post-post-module-es2015.js:240 {status: -1, error: "There was an error with the request: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/VID_20200908_114957.mp4: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)"
```

Looking only at the error message, we can conclude it's a permission issue, so I tried use [cordova-plugin-android-permissions](https://github.com/NeoLSN/cordova-plugin-android-permissions#readme) and request READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission. No success, the app has the permission but the error remains the same.

This is part of the code used to upload

```
private chooseContentUsingCameraPlugin(SOURCE: number) {
    const options: CameraOptions = {
        destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.ALLMEDIA,
        sourceType: SOURCE
    };
    this.camera.getPicture(options).then((contentUrl: string) => {
        if (contentUrl.indexOf('://') === -1)
            contentUrl = 'file://' + contentUrl;
        const queryIndex = contentUrl.lastIndexOf('?');
        if (queryIndex !== -1)
            contentUrl = contentUrl.substring(0, queryIndex);
        console.log('file url -> ', contentUrl);
        this.startUpload(contentUrl);
    }, (err) => this.onUploadError(err));
}

private startUpload(fileUrl){
    ...
    this.nativeHttp.uploadFile(req.url, null, headers, fileUrl, fileName).then(res => {
        let data = res.data;
        if (res.data && (req.responseType === undefined || req.responseType === 'json'))
            data = JSON.parse(res.data);
        console.log(data)
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
    });
}
```

can someone explain what could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the file you're trying to upload is not in the scope of your permission. This is what the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) says:

> This is a soft restricted permission which cannot be held by an app it its full form until the installer on record whitelists the permission. Specifically, if the permission is whitelisted the holder app can access external storage and the visual and aural media collections while if the permission is not whitelisted the holder app can only access to the visual and aural medial collections. Also the permission is immutably restricted meaning that the whitelist state can be specified only at install time and cannot change until the app is installed. For more details see [PackageInstaller.SessionParams.setWhitelistedRestrictedPermissions(Set)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInstaller.SessionParams#setWhitelistedRestrictedPermissions(java.util.Set%3Cjava.lang.String%3E)).